# php echo print � instead of balnk space for mysql records

Tags: php, html

i'm using php to get data from mysql and show result to the front end, so now the problem is my php prints �  this charecter instead of balnk space, please suggest me to romove the special charecter

Comment: preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);

Comment: so, how can i replace � with blank space

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the META tag either (like this, or the HTML4 or XHTML version of it):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

For Mysql  And PHP

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

// delivery
// php.ini did not have a default charset, 
// (it was commented out, shared host) and
// no http encoding was specified in the apache headers.
// this made apache send out a utf-8 header
// (and perhaps made php actually send out utf-8)
// ***notice "utf-8", with dash, this is a php encoding***

```
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
```

Comment: i tried this but not working